# MySQL query, how to use string in multiple ways?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a MySql query which will construct a string using the CONCAT function within 2 loops.

I'm wondering if a string can be used both as a variable and a reference to a field in a table?

My code so far is below, which is returning some syntax error near the UPDATE line:

```
    ...

WHILE x  <= 5 DO
      WHILE y  <= 3 DO
                SELECT @str_data = CONCAT(str,'data_',x); 
        SELECT @str_data = CONCAT(str,'_',y); 

        SELECT @variable:= @str_data FROM sometable WHERE id = '@counter + y';

        UPDATE anothertable SET @str_data = @variable WHERE id = '@counter + y';

            SET  y = y + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET  x = x + 1;
    SET @counter = counter + 3;
END WHILE;
```

I've checked all variables are set.

On a side note I may not be using the concat correctly, since I saw it being used differently in multiple examples. I intend for the
format to end up as: 'data_x_y'. (By adding the '_y' to the end of the current string.  :=  ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start at the beginning:
Change this code:

```
SELECT @str_data = CONCAT(str,'data_',x); 
SELECT @str_data = CONCAT(str,'_',y);
```

To :

```
SET @str_data = CONCAT(str, 'data_',x,'_',y);
```

I'm wondering why you are mixing DECLARE variables *(str)* with @vars *(@str_data)*, it looks very confused.

So this code: `SELECT @variable:= @str_data FROM sometable WHERE id = @counter + y;`

Does not do what you think it does. It just selects `@str_data` 0 or more times, whilst setting @variable.
You need to remove the `'` quotes from that if you want MySQL to add `@counter + y` because with a quote it will just evaluate to 0 and not match.

This code is incorrect:

```
UPDATE anothertable SET @str_data = @variable WHERE id = '@counter + y';
```

Change it to:

```
UPDATE anothertable SET fieldx = @variable WHERE id = @counter + y;
```

Note that SQL is not php, you cannot use @vars as placeholders for dynamic column names.
It really makes no sense.
I guess you are trying to come up with a string holding a dynamic column name and doing a update on that column.
Forget about using this approach, it will never work in SQL, also this is not the way SQL is supposed to work.

**What to do instead**

Change your table into this format

```
Table proper
  x integer
  y integer
  value varchar
  otherfields .....
```

Now you can just update with

```
 UPDATE proper SET value = @var WHERE x = 1 and y = 2;
```

Much cleaner and much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this was the issue. I need the string to be a reference to a field in a table. The string conetent itself (example: "data_1_2"), will become the name of a field which is used.

Comment: @user, use php if you must, but it will be slow for large tables, see my update to the answer instead.